# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to call a method using if..else. Below is the C# code from which i am trying  to send a string country to get selected from dropdown. I expect method WePay() to get  called. But getting the element not visible exception.

```
String country = "United States - US Dollars ($)";

new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("CountrySelector"))).SelectByText(country);

if (country != "United States - US Dollars ($)")
{
    PayPal();
}
else
{
    WePay();
}
```

Below is the C# code for method `WePay()`

```
public void WePay()
{
    wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@onclick='ValidateSubmit()']")).Click();
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("addAmount")).Click();
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("addAmount")).SendKeys("10");
    wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@onclick='PayNow();']")).Click();
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("new-cc")).Click();
    new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("Card_TransactionTypeId"))).SelectByText("Visa");
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("Number")).SendKeys("4003830171874018");
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVV")).SendKeys("527");
    new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("Card_ExpirationMonth"))).SelectByText("10");
    new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("Card_ExpirationYear"))).SelectByText("2020");
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("saved-address")).Click();
    new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("AddressSelector"))).SelectByValue("69918");
    wd.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton")).Click();

}
```

Comment: In the first statement u r assigning a string to variable, and in the 3rd statement u r comparing the variable with same string. What is the point in select the string from list box there? and the strings are same, why it will go to else condition? it should goto if condition and call Paypal() right?

Comment: I am selecting it because i want to click the listbox and pick the same parameter which i assigned to a string variable from multiple options. and of course if the strings will be the same in that case it should go to WePay() instead of PayPal(). I have written a condition "!="(not equals to)

Comment: Please post where and how the exception is thrown. As per you code, the method WePay will not be called until unless the if condition is failed which will be always true.

Answer (score 0):

We can help you better, if you let us know what error message you are getting, and where exactly in the code you are getting the error.

I am just reframing your code below in Java:

```
String country = "United States - US Dollars ($)";
Select select=new Select(wd.FindElement(By.Id("CountrySelector"))
select.selectByVisibleText(country);  //Here selects the country
//Now to cross check, get the value which is selected by below statement.
String returnSelectedCountry=select.getFirstSelectedOption(); //This will actually fetch the value from the listbox
if(!country.equals(returnSelectedCountry)) //Comparing the string var with actual val selected
  PayPal();
else
  WePay();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I had two solutions for this:

1. Use **Wait**, when interacting with elements especially when navigating through different pages. Most of the times JS is trying to interact with the HTML element before it has been loaded. In this case I extended the Selenium Wait with my own method that for given time checked/waited for the element condition.
2. When using Chrome/IE drivers keep in mind that some elements even load and present can't be handled properly. In my case *Finish* and *Go Back* buttons were at the bottom of the visible part of the screen and I had to use *scroll-down* option in order to interact with them.

Hope it helps.